# createAlias on a Detached Criteria (GORM)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

For a Grails project, I need it to sort by field of associated entity. Like *fetch entries sorted by authors name*:

```
def crteria = new DetachedCriteria(Entry)
criteria.list {
  order('author.name', 'asc')
}
```

Current example will fail with:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: author.name of: Entry
```

It's common problem with Hibernate, and usually done by introducting an alias for `author`, like:

```
criteria.createAlias('author')
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc('author.name'))
```

But the problem that Grails `gorm.DetachedCriteria` doesn't have such method, throws `NoSuchMethodException`. And I don't want to use plain `hibernate.DetachedCritera` instead, because need to support legacy code, written with Groovy criterias.

How I can add such alias? or how apply this sort w/o it?

Maybe there is a was to create a `hibernate.DetachedCriteria`, add alias, and then convert it to `gorm.DetachedCriteria`?

-

PS what's crazy, groovy `order('author.name', 'asc')` works fine for Integration tests. Fails only on a real app, `grails run-app`.

Comment: Have you already tried using `author` as association? `criteria.list { author { order('name', 'asc') } }`

Comment: yes, I've tried. It's just ignored at this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can get the DetachedCriteria from the GORM criteria builder any time and modify it with HibernateCriteriaBuilder.getHibernateDetachedCriteria(query).

The GORM DetachedCriteria is only a builder interface for the underlying Hibernate DetachedCriteria.

Comment: It's a good idea. But the problem that that if I do it before applying GORM criteria, this order is ignored (I belive original query just cloned, so I cannot aplly GORM stuff to original criteria). And I cannot apply it after GORM call, because `crit.list {}` returns actual list. Seem that I need to get access to Hibernate  _inside_ `crit.list {}` closure, just at the moment when GORM building Hibernate Criteria.

Comment: @Igor: Why don't  you use the constructed Hibernate criteria for executing the listing? Will it return different domain instances than the query executed with GORM's crit.list()?

Comment: Because existing code wasn't compatible with this classes. But now I've rewritten this part and using HibernateCriteriaBuilder instead, works fine. I should accept your answer probably

Answer (score 2):

> How I can add such alias?

We [cannot](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/1727) in DetachedCriteria as you mentioned.

> how apply this sort w/o it?

Other options include `withCriteria`, `createCriteria` and various other ways. The laziest but dirty way I can think now would be:

```
Entry.where{ }.collect()?.sort{ it.author?.name }
```

which I think you would have tried as well. :)

Comment: That Jira link is now dead -- appears to have been moved to [Github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/1727).

In [this 2019 comment](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/1727#issuecomment-172868319), Graeme noted that: "...use of createAlias is not supported, we have added the ability to define an alias during detached criteria construction." and "I believe this largely solves the requirement of this issue.", with the example `employee{'region', 'r')` allowing usage like `groupProperty('r.continent')`